# Disconnect or disable deployment option from azure webapp

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-deployment

I am running auto deployment pipeline connected with azure webapp. I want to disable deployment by pipeline for a certain period and enable again after finishing pipeline. I couldn't found any azure CLI regarding this task. Is there any azure pipeline task or azure CLI for performing this task.[image]

Comment: What do you want - Disabling the pipe manually for sometime or run only one build at a time ?

Comment: Disabling the pipeline for sometime and enable again by pipeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can disconnect to your deployment source by using the below command:**

```
az webapp deployment source delete --resource-group {your-resource-group} --name {your-app-service-name}
```

**For more information you can refer :**

[Similar Microsoft Q & A Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/629269/how-can-i-disconnect-my-deployment-source-from-my.html)

[Microsoft Documentation for Webapp Deployment Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/source?view=azure-cli-latest)